# ¿Cómo contar el número de personas por pais JS?

Tags: javascript

como puedo contar el numero de personas de cada pais, por ejemplo tengo esta lista:

```
students = [
  { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@gmail.com', country_id: 1 },
  { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com', country_id: 2 },
  { name: 'Daniela', email: 'daniela@gmail.com', country_id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mónica', email: 'monica@gmail.com', country_id: 2 }
];

countryName = "Mexico";

countries = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Mexico', },
  { id: 2, name: 'Colombia' }
];
```

lo que necesito es saber como contar la cantidad de personas de cada pais, si son 3 personas de colombia que return "3"

Agradezco la ayuda amigos

```
 function countStudents(students, countries, countryName) {

  countries.forEach((el, i) => Object.keys(el).forEach(entry => students[i][entry] = el[entry]));
  return students;
 
 }

 console.log(countStudents(students, countries, countryName));
```

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado mediante un [mcve]. Aquí no hacemos los deberes de los demás. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: No muestres solo el enunciado, _muestra lo que has intentado_ y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. [es.so] no es un sitio de tutorías. Como te han indicado, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo modificando tu función:

```js
students = [
  { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@academlo.com', country_id: 1 },
  { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com', country_id: 2 },
  { name: 'Daniela', email: 'daniela@gmail.com', country_id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mónica', email: 'monica@gmail.com', country_id: 2 }
];

countries = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Mexico', },
  { id: 2, name: 'Colombia' }
];

 function countStudents(students, countries, countryName) {
    let total_estudiantes=0;

  //Busco el pais primero para saber si existe
    let indice = countries.findIndex(pais => pais.name == countryName);
  if(indice>-1)
  {
    for(i=0;i<students.length;i++){
        if(students[i]["country_id"]==countries[indice]["id"])
      {
        //Sumo los estudiantes
        total_estudiantes++;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return total_estudiantes;
 
 }
 
 console.log(countStudents(students,countries,"Mexico")); 
 console.log(countStudents(students,countries,"Colombia"));
```

Allí te comente por si dan dudas, pero avísame si no entiendes y si de adapta

Comment: Muchas gracias, el codigo si se adapta. lo comprendi un poco, si puedes explicarmelo a detalle para terminar de comprenderlo te lo agradecería. gracias por tu atencion.

Comment: Claro, mira el **findIndex*** busco en el array de countries a ver si primero hay y que me diga el indice (posición donde esta) y con eso comparo en tu array students donde están todos los estudiantes y los sumo y los retorno

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias! no entendia como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

primero puedes recorrer el arreglo de paises y por cada pais buscar cuantos alumnos estan en ese pais y luego guardar el resultado en un arreglo.

```
function countStudents(){
    var resultado = [];

    //Recorrer el arreglo de los paises
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {

        //Filtrar los estudiantes que tiene el pais
        var estudiantes = students.filter(function (obj) {
                            return obj.country_id === countries[i].id;
                       });

        //Guardar el resultado
        resultado.push({ country :countries[i].name, total: estudiantes.length  });
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Ya entendi tu pregunta tu le pasas el nombre del país y te regresa solo la cantidad de estudiantes en el país. Con esta funcion puedes hacerlo

```
function countStudents2(countryName){
        //Buscar el país por nombre
        var country = countries.filter(function (obj) {
                                return obj.name === countryName;
                           })[0];

        if (country == null) {return 0;}

        var estudiantes = students.filter(function (obj) {
                                return obj.country_id === country.id;
                           });

        return estudiantes.length;

    }
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge, el codigo si funciona